# Facebook authentication issue at Login

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am using a Facebook login in my iPhone application, but when I click on the login button and the `FBSession` starts, it's showing an error "You are are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again."

Here is the code I am using:

```
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:FacebookID 
    permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"read_stream",@"public_profile",@"email", nil] 
    urlSchemeSuffix:nil tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {

    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}

[[FBSession activeSession]handleDidBecomeActive];
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];
FBSessionLoginBehavior behviour = FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;
[session openWithBehavior:behviour completionHandler:^(FBSession *session1, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",error.localizedDescription);
        [appDelegate removeHudView:nil];

    }
    if (session1.accessTokenData.accessToken) {


    }
}];
```

And also the screen sort of My simulator.

If anyone knows about how to handle this case, please help me.

[image]

Comment: I think you are not using SDK 4.x

Comment: I've seen it on SDK 4.0.1 and 4.4 today.